# how do I fix input string was not in a correct format error

Tags: c#, winforms

The first one is function with query to access maxdeathnumber from table tblDDDDriver by using LicenseNumber and show it in textbox and datatype of column LicenseNumber is of decimal(18,0) which is one of the field or column name in tblDDDDriver. The second one is what i coded to access that function. Now when i click the button i shows the error input string was not in a correct format

[Image Linke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvtnr.jpg)

```
public DataTable GetMaxDeathNo(decimal LicenseNumber)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=tprojectDB;");
     string sql = "select Max(DeathNumber) as DeathNumber from tblDDDDeath where LicenseNumber=@LicenseNumber";/*"select Max(Value) from tblv where Licenseno=@licenseno"*/;
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseNumber", LicenseNumber);
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);
     return dt;
}



DataTable dd = dc.GetMaxDeathNo(Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text));
if (dd.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     txtdeathaccidentno.Text = dd.Rows[0]["DeathNumber"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: debug step by step and check on which line u r getting the error

Comment: What is value of `txtlicensenumber.Text` ?

Comment: there should be some int/decimal value in txtlicensenumber.Text

Answer (score 2):

Your `Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text)` is getting a string with invalid characters.

Try changing it to:

```
Decimal d;
if (Decimal.TryParse(txtlicensenumber.Text, out d))
{
  DataTable dd = dc.GetMaxDeathNo(d);
  if (dd.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
      txtdeathaccidentno.Text = dd.Rows[0]["DeathNumber"].ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Decimal.Parse(txtlicensenumber.Text)
```